# Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.maze is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

new to js and html. have tried different answers here and many websites but for some reaon my code is still not working. i have created a plugin called mazePlugin.js, another script called test.js and my html file called test.html.
once a button is clicked the test script is invoked, sends an ajax request to my server(checked it works) and upon success it attempts to call my plugin and draw a maze. i know there might be problems with where i define the canvas. but that is not my current issue.

my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />

     <title>test page</title> </head> <body>

     <p id="paragraph">first paragraph</p>
     <p id="paragraph2">2nd paragraph</p>
     <input id="button" type="button" value="start game"/>

     <form>
     Name:<br/>
     <input id="name" type="text"/><br/>
     Columns:<br/>
     <input id="col" type="number"/><br/>
     Rows:<br/>
     <input id="row" type="number"/> </form>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/mazePlugin.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/test.js"></script>
     </body> 
    </html>
```

my plugin

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.maze = function (data) {
     var mazeObject = {
         draw: function() {
             var rows = data["Rows"];
             var cols = data["Cols"];
             var cellWidth = 300 / cols;
             var cellHeight = 300 / rows;
             var initialRow = data["Start"]["Row"];
             var initialCol = data["Start"]["Col"];
             var mazeAsString = data["Maze"];
             //draws the maze
             var current = 0;
             for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                 for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                     if (mazeAsString[current] == '1') {
                         context.fillRect(cellWidth * j, cellHeight * i, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                     }
                     current++;
                 }
             }
             //creating players image
             var united = new Image();
             united.src = "../Style/united.png";
             united.onload = function() {
                 context.drawImage(united, initialRow, initialCol, cellWidth, cellHeight);
             }
             return this;
         }
     };
     return mazeObject;
   }; 
}(jQuery));
```

my test.js

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "mazeCanvas";
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    canvas.style = "border:2px black solid";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var rows = $('#row').val();
    var cols = $('#col').val();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var mazeObject;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Http://localhost:52800/api/Maze",
        data: { 'name':name, 'rows':rows, 'cols':cols },
        success: function (data) {

            mazeObject = $.fn.maze(data);
            mazeObject.draw();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('an error has occurred');
        }
    });
});
```

the response i get is
test.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.maze is not a function
    at Object.success (test.js:40)
    at fire (jquery-3.2.1.js:3317)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.js:3447)
    at done (jquery-3.2.1.js:9272)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.js:9514)

Comment: Why are you creating a jQuery plugin? You should write a normal function.

Comment: we are requested to do this. we will be using the plugin later on

Comment: we were requested to use ajax aswell :(

Comment: Make sure your plugin is loaded AFTER you load JQuery.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It is. You can see the imports in the HTML.

Comment: This is completely unrelated but your HTML is poorly formatted, oh and too much white-space in JavaScript can have negative effects on performance. With that out of the way... Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I would edit / reformat your question if I could, but it appears that the edit queue is full. Also you could use dirtymarkup.com to help you tidy your code, it's really simple to use and doesn't take more than 10-20 seconds to tidy your code.

Comment: @Mango Those of us whose vision is not as good as yours appreciate the extra indentation for readability. If you're worried about whitespace creating a larger download in production, either use tabs or run your code through a minimizer.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors when loading the page ? Are you sure the path is correct and the maze plugin is loaded ?

Comment: i have managed to solve the issue only by moving the creation of the canvas to the html file. is there a different way to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly calling your plugin. It should be:

```
mazeObject = $.maze(data);
```

Comment: It would be `$().maze(data)`. If they wanted a static function, they would assign to `$.maze` instead of `$.fn.maze`.